# Gunicorn and flask-restplus response caching

Tags: python-3.x, rest, gunicorn, flask-restplus

I have flask-restplus based APIs in
production/test environment with Gunicorn. The
problem is if sometime an error comes it is
handled well by error handling logic but when
it is resolved I have to restart the Gunicorn
manually. If I don't restart it provides same result as
they were because of error. I am not sure if it is
gunicorn problem specifically or something
else. If anyone has any idea about it, please
share your views. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are in development mode: use --reload flag

```
 gunicorn --reload <rest of the command>
```

You can also use it in production but it is not preferred method.